# Kuna Code activation error by API, how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good day!
I am trying to use the API of the **Kuna.io** exchange

There is a method in the documentation: /v3/auth/kuna_codes/redeem

I get the error:

> {"messages": ["signature_is_incorrect"]}

Works correctly with other methods

```
import requests
import time
import hmac
import hashlib

url = "https://api.kuna.io/v3/auth/kuna_codes/redeem"
api_path = "/v3/auth/kuna_codes/redeem"

secret_key = 'key'
public_key = 'key'

nonce = str(int(time.time()*1000.0))
body = str('')
msg = api_path+nonce+body

kun_signature = hmac.new(secret_key.encode('ascii'), msg.encode('ascii'), hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()


payload = {"code": "ZC7Xr-TBcfa-DW3hg-xNUr8-cxnp2-CHada-QT9Yr-L14DZ-5pyjA-UAH-KCode"}
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    'kun-nonce': nonce,
    'kun-apikey': public_key,
    'kun-signature': kun_signature,
    }

response = requests.request("PUT", url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

My suspicions are that the method is wrong since the signature works correctly with other methods.

Answer (score 0):

The signature should contain a body. Try with this one

```
payload = {"code": "ZC7Xr-TBcfa-DW3hg-xNUr8-cxnp2-CHada-QT9Yr-L14DZ-5pyjA-UAH-KCode"} 
body = json.dumps(payload)
msg = api_path+nonce+body
```